# Paypal Credit option is not available in Magento Backend

Tags: magento-1.9, checkout, payment-methods, paypal, paypal-express

For my Magento 1.9 websites, I want to enable the **paypal credit** option but this option is not displayed in my backend. But if I `changed the Merchant Country from UK to US automatically “Enable Paypal Credit” option is available`. I have found a tutorial regarding this, but when I  follow the steps the option ‘Enable Paypal Credit’ isn’t available, please check tutorials links below.

Tutorials Link :- https://medium.com/@Magento_expert/magento-tutorial-how-to-set-up-paypal-credit-and-paypal-payment-advanced-1d1777850439

Please help me if I missed something while magento / Paypal setup and how to enable paypal credit for UK.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: also experiencing same issue. Did you ever resolve?

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/147190)